# Get Option according object value

Tags: scala

I have this object:

```
case class Student(name: String, dateTime: DateTime)
```

Inside this function i get Student `object` but the `DateTime` is sometimes `null` and sometimes not:

```
def foo(student: Student): Unit = {

}
```

This is new function that gets `Option[DateTime]`

```
def foo2(option: Option[DateTime]): Unit = {

}
```

So when call `foo2` i need to check first if my `DateTime` is `null` and then call `foo2(None)` or `DateTime` is not `null` and call `Some(student)`.

So my question is: instead if using this:

```
def foo(student: Student): Unit = {

   if (student == null) foo2(None)
   else foo2(Some(student))
}
```

Any idea how to determine the `student` value and send it to `foo2` function without using `if-else` ?

Answer (score 4):

Change your class construct to reflect the nature of the null:

```
 case class Student(name: String, dateTime: Option[DateTime])

 object Student{
   def apply(name: String, dateTime: DateTime) = new Student(name, Option(dateTime))
 }
```

The default `apply` of `Option` will handle converting `null` to a `None`.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written in `foo` can be shortened to `foo2(Option(student))`.
But it is, probably, not what you really want, because your `foo2` accepts an option of `DateTime`, not of `Student`.

So, I am guessing, what you are trying to do is:

```
foo2(Option(student).flatMap(s => Option(s.dateTime))
```

Better yet, as the answer suggests, make `dateTime` optional in `Student` to begin with.